# compatibility html document

Tags: html, accessibility

I am using the tool: http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php#output_div. And I get this error:

> Line 3, Column 2: Document does not validate.
>
> ```
> <html lang="nl">
>       <head>
>           <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
>           <meta name=" ...
> ```

#### Fail Examples

> The document does not validate to declared specification - 'strict'
> doctype does not allow target attribute.

But I don't understand what is wrong with the document.

This is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="nl">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<meta name="author" content="OntwikkelSmartInstant" />
<meta name="dcterms.rightsHolder" content="© 2015 - OntwikkelSmartInstant" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="Nieuws" />
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

                    
                <title>Nieuws</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/scf2/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scf2/jquery/jquery.scf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Config/ScfScripts.js?scf=%2fscf2%2f"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Config/GlobalScripts.js?ts=2014-12-10T17:26:53"></script><script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    $j(function(){$j.scf.start({"locale":1043,"conflict":true});onLoad()});
    function onLoad() {
    //empty
    }
/*]]>*/
</script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scf2/jquery/smoothness/sms-jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Config/GlobalStyles.css?ts=2015-06-05T15:04:10" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/SmartInstant-Framework/Design/Special-stylesheets/printcss.css?layout=1739" media="print" />

                <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="SmartInstant RSS feed" href="/rss.rss" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/Config/Scripts/modernizrjs.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/Config/Scripts/respondjs.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body id="si_news" class="spp">
            
                        
                        <div class="wrap">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row" id="content">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">                         
                                        <div class="row kruimelrow">
        
        
        
            
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                


<div class="sml_box sml_si_datatablelist_box"><div><div id="sml_si_datatablelist_1" class="smartlet sml_si_datatablelist">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            
        <li><a href="/">Welkom bij SmartInstant</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/SmartInstant2-Actueel.html">Actueel</a></li>
    
            <li class="active">Nieuws</li>
        </ol>
    <div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col_content col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
                    


<div class="sml_box sml_si_custom_box"><div><div id="sml_si_custom_1" class="smartlet sml_si_custom"> <h1 class="pageTitle">Nieuws</h1>

            <p class="intro">Nieuws</p>     
        






 <div class="clear"></div> </div></div></div>  



<div class="sml_box sml_si_sqllist_box"><div><div id="sml_si_sqllist_1" class="smartlet sml_si_sqllist">


        <ul class="media-list">
        <li class="media">
            
                <a class="pull-left" href="/Januari-Schaatsersbond-waarschuwt-voor-roekeloosheid">
                    <img src="/designs/gallery/sky101.jpg?hid=img;w=100;crl=0;crt=0;crw=1024;crh=768" alt="Schaatsen wordt gevaarlijk" />
                </a>
            
            <div class="media-body">
                <a href="/Januari-Schaatsersbond-waarschuwt-voor-roekeloosheid"><h2 class="media-heading">Schaatsersbond waarschuwt voor roekeloosheid</h2></a>
                <p><em>22-1-2010</em> - asd</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    
        <li class="media">
            
                <a class="pull-left" href="/Januari-Inbreker-laat-huissleutel-met-adreslabel-achter">
                    <img src="/designs/gallery/sky102.jpg?hid=img;w=100;crl=0;crt=0;crw=1024;crh=768" alt="Dief" />
                </a>
            
            <div class="media-body">
                <a href="/Januari-Inbreker-laat-huissleutel-met-adreslabel-achter"><h2 class="media-heading">Inbreker laat huissleutel met adreslabel achter</h2></a>
                <p><em>12-1-2010</em> - TILBURG - Een 30-jarige Tilburger is dinsdag aangehouden voor een inbraak in het chalet van de kinderboerderij aan de Bisschop Bekkerslaan in zijn woonplaats. </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    
        <li class="media">
            
                <a class="pull-left" href="/Januari-Noordzeewater-valt-mee-bij-nieuwsjaarsduik">
                    <img src="/designs/gallery/sky103.jpg?hid=img;w=100;crl=0;crt=0;crw=1024;crh=768" alt="Nieuwjaarsduik" />
                </a>
            
            <div class="media-body">
                <a href="/Januari-Noordzeewater-valt-mee-bij-nieuwsjaarsduik"><h2 class="media-heading">Noordzeewater valt mee bij nieuwsjaarsduik </h2></a>
                <p><em>19-1-2011</em> - SCHEVENINGEN - De watertemperatuur was een graadje of zes, de lucht twee tot vier graden minder. De 6500 mensen die bij Scheveningen meededen aan de nieuwsjaarsduik, kunnen het niet al te koud hebben gehad.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    
        <li class="media">
            
                <a class="pull-left" href="/Februari-Lentefeest-op-Kinderboerderij-Heuvelveen">
                    <img src="/designs/gallery/sky104.jpg?hid=img;w=100;crl=0;crt=0;crw=1024;crh=768" alt="Geit" />
                </a>
            
            <div class="media-body">
                <a href="/Februari-Lentefeest-op-Kinderboerderij-Heuvelveen"><h2 class="media-heading">Lentefeest op Kinderboerderij Heuvelveen</h2></a>
                <p><em>28-2-2011</em> - Tijdens de krokusvakantie staat kinderboerderij Heuvelveen in het teken van de lente. Alle kinderen zijn van harte welkom om mee te doen met de spel- en knutselactiviteiten. </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    
        <li class="media">
            
                <a class="pull-left" href="/Februari-Laatste-Schaatsdagen-winterseizoen">
                    <img src="/designs/gallery/sky105.jpg?hid=img;w=100;crl=0;crt=0;crw=1024;crh=768" alt="Persoon op de schaatsbaan" />
                </a>
            
            <div class="media-body">
                <a href="/Februari-Laatste-Schaatsdagen-winterseizoen"><h2 class="media-heading">Laatste Schaatsdagen winterseizoen</h2></a>
                <p><em>2-11-2012</em> - Na ruim drie maanden is het gedaan: het ijs wordt ontdooit, de schaatsen gaan weer in het vet, de baan wordt afgebouwd.  In drie maanden tijd bonden een record aantal ijsliefhebbers de schaatsen onder de voeten. De schaatsbaan in het centrum trok ruim 30% meer bezoekers dan vorig jaar.
ï é è ü € 
</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    

    
<div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        
            
            
            
            
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
                    


<div class="sml_box sml_si_menu_box"><div><div id="sml_si_menu_1" class="smartlet sml_si_menu">
        <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/Over-SmartInstant2">SmartInstant</a></li>
    
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/SmartInstant2-Actueel.html">Actueel</a>
        <ul class="list-group l1">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/SmartInstant2-Actueel/Nieuws.html">Nieuws</a></li>
    
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/SmartInstant2-Actueel/Evenementen.html">Evenementen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Over-ons.html">Over ons</a></li>
    
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Informatie.html">Informatie</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>
                </div>
            
        
        
        
        
            
            <div class="col-md-3">
                


<div class="sml_box sml_si_sqllist_box"><div><h2>Categorieën</h2></div><div><div id="sml_si_sqllist_2" class="smartlet sml_si_sqllist">
<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-unstyled"><span style="visibility:hidden"></span><a class="list-group-item" href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/SmartInstant2-Actueel/Nieuws.html?p=14"><span class="badge">4</span>Binnenland</a><span style="visibility:hidden"></span></li><li class="list-unstyled"><span style="visibility:hidden"></span><a class="list-group-item" href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/SmartInstant2-Actueel/Nieuws.html?p=17"><span class="badge">1</span>Opmerkelijk</a><span style="visibility:hidden"></span></li></ul>
<div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="header">
                                    <div class="row headerrow">
        
        
        
            
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                    


<div class="sml_box sml_si_custom_box dontprint logobox"><div><div id="sml_si_custom_2" class="smartlet sml_si_custom"> 

    <a class="logo" href="/">
        <img src="/SmartInstant-Framework/Design/Design-Images/Logo.jpg" alt="SmartInstant 3.0" />
    </a>
 <div class="clear"></div> </div></div></div>  
            </div>
        
    
        
        
        
            
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                


<div class="sml_box sml_si_simplelist_box list-horizontal text-right"><div><div id="sml_si_simplelist_1" class="smartlet sml_si_simplelist"><ul><li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Beheer/HeaderLinks/Home-1.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Beheer/HeaderLinks/Sitemap-1.html">Sitemap</a></li><li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Beheer/HeaderLinks/Contact-1.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Beheer/HeaderLinks/RSS-1.html">RSS</a></li></ul>
<div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    </div>
                                    <div class="row navigationrow">
        
        
        
            
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                


<div class="sml_box sml_si_menu_box"><div><div id="sml_si_menu_2" class="smartlet sml_si_menu"><nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Over-SmartInstant2">SmartInstant</a></li>
                
                    <li class="active"><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/SmartInstant2-Actueel.html">Actueel</a></li>
                
                    <li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Over-ons.html">Over ons</a></li>
                
                    <li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Informatie.html">Informatie</a></li>
                </ul>
                
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="/Zoeken-1" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" title="Type hier uw zoekterm" placeholder="Zoek" tabindex="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="searchconcept" id="c" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="Zoek" class="btn btn-default">Zoeken</button>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav><div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="container" id="footer">
                            <div class="row footerrow">
        
        
        
            
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                


<div class="sml_box sml_si_simplelist_box list-horizontal text-right">

<div><div id="sml_si_simplelist_2" class="smartlet sml_si_simplelist"><ul><li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Beheer/Footerlinks/Help-1.html">Help</a></li><li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Beheer/Footerlinks/Disclaimer-1.html">Disclaimer</a></li><li><a href="/Welkom-bij-SmartInstant/Beheer/Footerlinks/Bladeren-op-trefwoord.html">Bladeren op trefwoord</a></li></ul>

<div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    
        
        
        
    </div>
                        </div>
                    
            
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I pasted your code there, and it says: "Congratulations, no error!" Do you enter an URL? Do you have a proxy like CloudFlare before it?

Comment: Thank you. but you have check this options: WCAG 1.0 (Level AAA)  
   WCAG 2.0 (Level AAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error, even by checking WCAG 1.0 (Level AAA) or WCAG 2.0 (Level AAA).

However, it seems that the checker doesn't like the `http-equiv` attribute of that meta tag in line "3" (to me it seems like line 5).

This error can safely be ignored - it is only being thrown because the attribute is unrecognized, and whenever a real device sees an unrecognized attribute, it ignores the tag which probably wasn't meant for that device anyways (hint: `IE=edge` seems to refer to Internet Explorer)